# powerpivot excel- non-responsive Filtering of a KPI based on KPIs from two sheets

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot, kpi

Excuse the title, I cannot think of a better way to describe it.

I have sheets (sheet1, sheet2)[simplified for illustrative purposes]:

```
sheet1

MoYr | OnlineSales
Jan-18  50
Jan-17  22
Feb-18  12
..
Apr-18  44
Apr-17  12

sheet2

MoYr | OfflineSales
Jan-18  50
Jan-17  22
Feb-18  12
..
Apr-18  44
Apr-17  12
```

I have two KPIs summing the YTD sales

```
KPI1:=TOTALYTD:=calculate(sum(OnlineSales))
KPI2:=TOTALYTD:=calculate(sum(OfflineSales))
```

Then I have a `GRAND-KPI` which total the sales for both sheets:

`GrandKPI= KPI1 + KPI2`

`GrandKPI` is on `sheet2`. I noticed that when I filter `sheet2` on specific months, `KPI1` (from sheet1) will return the `TOTALYTD` amount irrespective of what filter I have on `sheet2`.

How can I get `KPI1` to respect the filter on `sheet2`?

Comment: How does your model look like? Are the date (MoYr) somewhere connect to eachother or a date table? I've have a feeling that they're not connected, and therefor PowerPivor doens't 'know' that sheet1 also needs to be filtered.

Comment: they are totally independent of each other but connecting them via relationship does not work because there are duplicate values in each data set

Comment: Yes, that’s normal behavior. You’ll need a separate Date Dimension, linked to both tables, to filter. I’ll work on an answer tomorrow. Do you have a sample sheet?

Comment: i don't have a sample sheet, can you use the data example in the initial post?